# How can I create a readable Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I'm doing some tests, and swapping out a Stream that usually comes from a web request with a stream I have created.

I create the stream like this:

```
MemoryStream responseDataStream = new MemoryStream();

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(responseDataStream))
{
    sw.Write(responseData);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}
```

However when my code tries to consume it:

`StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myStream);`

I get the error `Stream was not readable.`

I want to prepare my stream so that it is ready to be consumed. How can I do this?

Comment: Try set `stream.Position = 0;` before reading it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `StreamWriter` takes ownership of the stream you pass in the constructor. When the stream writer is closed, it will close the underlying stream as well. You need to use a different overload of the constructor, e.g. `new StreamWriter(responseDataStream, Encoding.UTF8, true)`.

Second, the stream is still at the position of the last write. You need to rewind it:

```
responseDataStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: When a memory stream is closed, because you have written to it and closed the streamwriter, does it just vanish into the ether then?

Comment: @NibblyPig No - but it's closed. It still allows you to call `ToArray` (that's the most common use case for a memory stream - reading a stream into a byte array or vice versa), but most other things are forbidden. This is no foreign concept - if you close a socket, surely you wouldn't expect it to still be able to receive data :)